# Spring Security + Vaadin: How to create custom non-JSP login form?

Tags: spring-security, vaadin

It's fairly easy to use custom JSP login page in Spring Security. Our application is based on Vaadin though and I don't want to have JSP login page. What I want is custom fancy login window created as Vaadin widget.

Well technically I can use Vaadin's **FormLayout** and name fields like **j_username** and **j_password** ... but this is Java class and not JSP file, so what do I specify in **http** Spring Security element? I mean:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page='MyLoginWindow.java or what?' />
</http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally unfamiliar with Spring Security, but one of our guys at Vaadin made a demo application a couple of years ago https://github.com/peholmst/SpringSecurityDemo. I don't know if it's still up-to-date or if it even answers your question, but perhaps you could have a look and see for yourself if you can get any answers from there. Otherwise you could perhaps ping Petter personally and see if he has any fresh ideas about the topic.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, it's more complex example of what @OlegYch suggested. It's injecting AuthenticationManager to Vaadin class, but not really using spring's filter chain

Answer (score 1):

Use LoginForm and in LoginListener use something like this

```
try {
  val authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, pass)
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext.setAuthentication(authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication))
} catch {
  case e: AuthenticationException => {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so this seems to work, but is it enough? Are Spring Security filters working normally with this approach or is there anything else to do?

Comment: nope, the filters will not be invoked, but you can always invoke the desired configuration by yourself, e.g. to apply session policy use    sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication,request , null)

Comment: ufff that's not very satisfying in my situation. I'll try to open bounty here asap.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below my approach. The code shows the functionality that occurs when clicking the login button.

```
loginBtn.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // Getting the helper for working with spring context
            // found here https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration   
            SpringContextHelper helper = new SpringContextHelper(getApplication());

            // Get the providerManagerBean
            ProviderManager authenticationManager = (ProviderManager)helper
                    .getBean("authenticationManager");

            // Get entered data for name and password
            String name = usernameEntered;
            String password = passwordEntered;

            // Validation
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(name) || StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
                getWindow().showNotification("Username or password cannot be empty", 
                        Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                try {
                    // Security functionality goes here
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);

                    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

                    // Set the authentication info to context      
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

                    // During the authentification the AppUser instance was set as 
                    // details, for more info about the user
                    AppUser user = (AppUser) authentication.getDetails();                        

                    if (user != null) {
                        // Switch the view after succesfull login
                        getApplication().getMainWindow().setContent(new ComboBoxUserStartsWith());

                    }
                } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                    // Display error occured during logining
                    getWindow().showNotification(e.getMessage(), Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah but you aren't using Spring Security filter chain, are you?

Comment: Yes, I don`t use them. Actually my knowledge in security says that if the Vaadin application is working by one URL(e.g. host:port/vaadinapp) and different views are changed inside Vaadin without redirection to other URLs. Such kind of security will be enough. May be I`m wrong, and will be pleased if you point vulnerabilities that may cause.

Comment: Yeah it usually is enough, but I am integrating our Vaadin app with another one and security will be handled by Spring Security for both of them

Comment: I have smth familiar. In my war there are two applications. One of them host:port/vaadinapp, and I use spring security for it as i mentioned. And by other URL host:port/mvcapp I have a spring MVC app. There I use <security:intercept-url> for different parts of application with different access roles