# Spring security vaadin Authetication manager bean

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin and Spring security. Last few days I was googling for the right example how to integrate spring security into vaadin application (not the servlet) so that the users can authenticate themselves using LoginForm vaadin component. Here is the code snippet that I used inside onlogin event:

```
login = new LoginForm();
login.addListener(new LoginForm.LoginListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onLogin(LoginEvent event) {
        if (event.getLoginParameter("username").isEmpty() || event.getLoginParameter("password").isEmpty()) {
            getWindow().showNotification("Please enter username and/or password", Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            SpringContextHelper helper = new SpringContextHelper(getApplication());
            authenticationManager = (ProviderManager)helper.getBean("authenticationManager");

            try {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(event.getLoginParameter("username"), event.getLoginParameter("password"));   
                Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                authentication.getDetails();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getWindow().showNotification(e.getMessage(), Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }                   
    }
});
```

When I try to login with my credentials that I described in applicationContext.xml file I got an error Null Pointer exception at this line:

```
 authenticationManager = (ProviderManager)helper.getBean("authenticationManager");
```

I know that the error is thrown by the getBean("authenticationManager"); method because it can't locate **"**authenticationManager**"** bean. The question would be: what is the **"**authenticationManager**"** in this context. Is it a class or bean that implements some kind of Spring security framework interface with special methods. Does anyone could provide an example of such bean (class, pojo and etc.). I descriped listeners and context-params in my web.xml as I found on the examples in the internet.

**WEB.XML**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Also I am providing a applicationContext.xml in which I describe authentication manager with plain username and password.

**APPLICATIONCONTEXT.XML**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <form-login />
   <logout />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="userrrr" password="passsssword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <user name="otheruser" password="otherpasss" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

So In short. Does anyone could provide me a working bean example, for my case, which can authenticate plain usernames and passwords that are described in applicationContext.xml file. If it helps I am using Vaadin 6, Maven, Hibernate, GlassFish and Sping security 3. I will greatly appreciate help because I am working on this issue for the last three days.

There are plenty examples on the internet but they are all unfinished, unclear, uses Vaadin application servelts or jsp login forms (not the application) and different techniques.

I choosed the way that is described in official vaadin wiki https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration?p%255Fr%255Fp%255F185834411%255Ftitle=Spring%2520Integration. But it is so poor and describes spring framework integration not security.

I found another example which looked me perfect [Spring Security + Vaadin: How to create custom non-JSP login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990617/spring-security-vaadin-how-to-create-custom-non-jsp-login-form) . But there I can't find detailed info about authenticationManager.

Also here is another nice example https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/373038. But it is using HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse for passing authetication details. I know that vaadin application class can implement HttpServletRequestListener interface with onRequestStart and onRequestEnd methods but how I can pass/use these requests to/with onLogin event.

So dear JAVA masters please help for a newbie JAVA JEDI programmer to choose a right way:)

**Spring Context helper class**

```
public class SpringContextHelper {  
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public SpringContextHelper(Application application) {
        ServletContext servletContext = ((WebApplicationContext) application.getContext()).getHttpSession().getServletContext();
        context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    }

    public Object getBean(final String beanRef) {
        return context.getBean(beanRef);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try org.springframework.security.authentication.**AuthenticationManager** interface instead of **ProviderManager**:

```
authenticationManager = (AuthenticationManager)helper.getBean("authenticationManager");
```

**EDIT.** Replace alias="authenticationManager" by id="authenticationManager in your conf.

Comment: No bean named **"authenticationManager"** is provided. From this error I see that I have to create **authenticationManager** bean. But I don't know how to implement such bean. What kind of interfaces and methods should it use?

Comment: It is provided by Spring Security. See your conf : **authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"**. Normally you do not need a custom implementation. Spring Security provide default one for you (ProviderManager).

Comment: You need to replace **alias="authenticationManager"** by **id="authenticationManager"**. i think it will do the trick.

Comment: I got the same error :( (No bean named "authenticationManager" is provided). Maybe I have to include some packages in  pom file. But I already added all related Spring-security packages to pom.

Comment: Also I changed from alias to id

Comment: Maybe there are problems with my context helper class. I edited the post

Comment: Are you sure that your APPLICATIONCONTEXT.XML is picked up by spring at sturtup?

Comment: No I am not. How I can ensure if it is? Sorry for dumb questions but I am new to spring

Comment: Just make some mistake in APPLICATIONCONTEXT.XML and resturt the application. You must see this exception **Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext*.xml]**. Your web application will not be able to serve requests.

Comment: What can I say. You are GOD. My applicationContext.xml was in different folder. I put it here this morning. I don't know why. Also the <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> is good. When I change alies to id then I get error in deployng time. One zillion thanks to you for the correct path.